# How can this be the same sql connection?

Tags: c#, database-connection, mariadb, mysql-connector

"select LAST_INSERT_ID()" is related to the connection. So i test in Mariadb 5.5.25, code as below:

```
string strConn = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin;database=changde2018;charset=utf8;Allow Zero Datetime=True";
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConn))
{
   connection.Open();
   MySqlCommand cmd = MySqlCommand("insert into t_data (gid) values(665)", connection);// gid is a autoincrease value
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connection.Close();
}

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConn))
{
   DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
   MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select LAST_INSERT_ID()", connection);
   da.Fill(dt2);
   Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[0][0].ToString());//expect 0, but it's as same as the last inserted value
}
```

I query in navicat by 'show status like 'Threads%''. After exe code above, the 'threads_connected' only increased one. This proves Mariadb does treat them as the same connection. Can this be why, I use two different MySqlConnection objects, is it because of the same connection string?

Comment: Connection pooling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mysqlconnector.Net documentation says on [connection pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) (highlighting is mine):

> The MySQL Connector/Net supports connection pooling for better
>   performance and scalability with database-intensive applications. **This
>   is enabled by default.** You can turn it off or adjust its performance
>   characteristics using the connection string options Pooling,
>   Connection Reset, Connection Lifetime, Cache Server Properties, Max
>   Pool Size and Min Pool Size. See Section 5.1.1, “Creating a
>   Connector/Net Connection String” for further information.
>
> **Connection pooling works by keeping the native connection to the
>   server live when the client disposes of a MySqlConnection.
>   Subsequently, if a new MySqlConnection object is opened, it will be
>   created from the connection pool, rather than creating a new native
>   connection. This improves performance.**

Since connection pooling is turned on by default, the database connection was not closed when you closed and disposed of the first mysqlconnection object and was reused by the next section of the code.

You can fully verify this using the [connection_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) function in sql.

Comment: thanks, that's the reason. I added connection para 'Connection Reset=True' and then 'select LAST_INSERT_ID()' returned the value based on sql-connection